# facing issue in scanning with "EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,UPC_E" android

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

Hello I am searching for proper scanning library since many days , i have tested all these following libraries

```
https://github.com/Credntia/MVBarcodeReader?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4457
https://github.com/zxing/zxing
https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/lib-demo-app
https://github.com/bobekos/SimpleBarcodeScanner
https://github.com/avaneeshkumarmaurya/Barcode-Reader
```

but facing same issue when ever i move my camera on surface like on table etc i am getting result even on empty things ,from these random barcode types EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,UPC_E" , please guide me how to fix this issue , but when i try https://cmbdn.cognex.com/ apk i am not getting this issue but this is paid library.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're facing? Are you getting results without having scanned a barcode?

Comment: when ever i move my camera on surface like on table etc i am getting result even on empty things ,from these random barcode types EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,UPC_E"

Comment: As an additional option you can try MLKit: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning

Comment: any other solution to fix this libarary